# ServiceStack V4 metadata index page - Trouble renaming operation names

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I have been customizing the metadata pages and have run into a funny issue where, in the IndexPageFilter filter event, attempting to rename an operation in OperationNames fails (only when not in Debug mode!).

What I am actually doing is clearing the list, and generating a new list of strings (actually hyperlinks) that show the **route and verbs** INSTEAD of the DTO class names.

So for example, "AuthenticateUser" would be shown as "POST /authenticate" (but it would actually be a hyperlink, pointing to the original, and still working AuthenticateUser details page something like api/json/metadata?op=AuthenticateUser).

The funny thing is that it works just fine when debug mode in SS is set to true:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig{DebugMode = true});
```

However, when it not debug mode, the index page will not show any links. So, I am wondering if I am off base in attempting this type of customization... or if this is a bug since it actually works great in debug mode.

Customizing the format of API documentation is a required feature for us, and we are trying to move away from Swagger (because of lack of support for complex type optional parameters). With the latest V4.32 updates, the SS native metadata pages are almost at a level where we can start using them in production...

**EDIT on Oct 3, 2014:**

I'm not sure I framed the question clearly so I will try again.

Here is a basic metadata index page: https://devlab-api.betasabrina.com/api/metadata

The operations here are named after the name of our request classes - but we do not want them named that way, since many of our developers do not use the ServiceStackClient, they would prefer routes, or a combination.

So the issue is, how to I make (take the first line for example) "AddRemoveServiceDomain" show up as its verb + route (POST /api/services/{ServiceGuid}/domains/{Domain}) ?

Currently, you can replace the text in Debug mode and all the operations show up - but not when SS Debug mode is set to false it becomes an empty list.

**EDIT on Oct 6, 2014**

Here is the code to repro the issue with the missing metadata on the index page:

```
  private void IndexPageFilter(IndexOperationsControl indexPage)
            {   
    //clear the original OperationNames
                indexPage.OperationNames.Clear();

//get a list of the new operation titles names we want to expose, sorted, etc
                var sortedPaths = this.RestPaths.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.AllowedVerbs)).OrderBy(r => r.Path).ThenBy(r => r.AllowedVerbs);


                foreach (var s in sortedPaths)
                {
    //only show routes with verbs
                    var verbs = s.AllowedVerbs != null ? s.AllowedVerbs.PadRight(10, ' ') : "";
                    verbs = verbs.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

                    var pathText = string.Format("{0} {1}", verbs, s.Path);
    //create an html link (I know this is a hack... and disables the JSON link)
                    var link = string.Format("<a href='json/metadata?op={0}'  >{1}</a>", s.RequestType.Name, pathText);
                    indexPage.OperationNames.Add(link);
                }

            }
```

Now, if

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig{DebugMode = true});
```

The code SS framework will allow those links to be generated and it will display as intended... however when Debug=false, the index page will show as empty (because the list of OperationNames dont match the request DTO class names).

I know what I am doing manipulating the index list is hacky... but perhaps this type of hack indicates that a deeper level of customization needs to be enabled on the metadata index page... or quite possibly I am attacking this customization issue incorrectly.

Thanks again for the hard work :)

Jordan

Comment: Please provide a copy of your customized metadata pages so we can repro the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `/metadata` page shows metadata on operations you have access to. When `DebugMode=true` it will show all operations but the links to the details page will be disabled. When `DebugMode=false` these services will be hidden.

Attributes that affect visibility of Services include ServiceStack's [Restrict attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services).

Comment: i was unaware of the Restrict attrib - that will help a future work issue so thanks. 

I have edits the question because im afraid it wasnt clear what I was trying to do... thanks again.